# Rest API java: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tutorialspoint.User

Tags: java, api, tomcat, jersey

I'm quite new to Java and REST API and I have the following problem. I follow that link  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm to learn how to build a REST API. I tried a few things, and I wanted to use my own package (com.ca) and updated my web.xml to the following:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0"> 
   <display-name>User Management</display-name> 
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>com.ca</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Nevertheless when I try to re-run the code on the server, and do a GET request I obtain the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tutorialspoint.User
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:677)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at com.ca.UserDao.getAllUsers(UserDao.java:28)
    at com.ca.UserService.getUsers(UserService.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems to still point on the previous package ( the one for the exercise), but I can't find why...Also if you have useful link about it ( how to setup the web.xml, every tag role,...) that would be helpful as well.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Here are the source files:
User.java:

```
package com.ca;

import java.io.Serializable;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement; 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 
@XmlRootElement(name = "user") 

public class User implements Serializable {  
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
   private int id; 
   private String name; 
   private String profession;  
   public User(){} 

   public User(int id, String name, String profession){  
      this.id = id; 
      this.name = name; 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }  
   public int getId() { 
      return id; 
   }  
   @XmlElement 
   public void setId(int id) { 
      this.id = id; 
   } 
   public String getName() { 
      return name; 
   } 
   @XmlElement
   public void setName(String name) { 
      this.name = name; 
   } 
   public String getProfession() { 
      return profession; 
   } 
   @XmlElement 
   public void setProfession(String profession) { 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }   
}
```

UserDao.java:

```
package com.ca;  

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.ObjectInputStream; 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;  

public class UserDao { 
   public List<User> getAllUsers(){ 

      List<User> userList = null; 
      try { 
         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         if (!file.exists()) { 
            User user = new User(1, "Mahesh", "Teacher"); 
            userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
            userList.add(user); 
            saveUserList(userList); 
         } 
         else{ 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
            userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject(); 
            ois.close(); 
         } 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }   
      return userList; 
   } 
   private void saveUserList(List<User> userList){ 
      try { 
         File file = new File("Users.dat"); 
         FileOutputStream fos;  
         fos = new FileOutputStream(file); 
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 
         oos.writeObject(userList); 
         oos.close(); 
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
   }    
}
```

UserService.java:

```
package com.ca;

import java.util.List; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/UserService") 

public class UserService {  
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();  
   @GET 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public List<User> getUsers(){ 
      return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
   }  
}
```

Update 2.0:
[Screenshot of the project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtGbC.png)

Now I have the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.81 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 404 - /REST-Example/rest/UserService/users</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>/REST-Example/rest/UserService/users</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The requested resource is not available.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.81</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<param-value>com.ca</param-value>` is this correct? Shouldn't it be `com.tutorialspoint`?

Comment: On a different point, most examples on tutorialspoint were written somewhere before 2012 and never updated. So some things are a bit outdated.

Comment: This is what it used to be, but I'd like to create a new API with the same files, so I decided to rename the package to com.ca

Comment: Well if you get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tutorialspoint.User` exception, you haven't changed the package structure of your classes.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry, I'm quite new to Java as well...

Comment: Try to clean the project by calling `project > clean` Eclipse menu and `Refresh`ing the project. If it still doesn't help, leave me a comment.

Comment: @ujulu It still doesn't work, I keep getting the same mistake

Comment: I don't see the reason why `com.tutorialspoint` package is still existing. The experiment you could do is go to `webapps` folder of Tomcat and delete the war file as well as the corresponding folder of your example application and build and redeploy again. If it still doesn't work we'll see the next step.

Comment: @ujulu I tried what you said, still the same error. I ran it both on eclipse/tomcat and on tomcat through webapps.

Comment: OK, right now I am at work. So if you can wait until the evening today, I'll try it out and tell you the result.

Comment: Works for me thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are missing some steps. I just followed the tutorial and everything works. The following is what I did:

1. Configure your system according to the instruction on tutorial site.
2. Create Eclipse `Dynamic Web Project`
3. Download Jersey 2.17 and expand it in a directory according to the instructions on the tutorial site.
4. Copy all of the JAR files except `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar` into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
5. Create the classes `User.java`, `UserDao.java`, `UserService.java` and `web.xml` in the folders as shown on the screenshot.
6. Right click on the project (in my example: REST-Example) and select `Export>WAR file` to export the project to war file.
7. Copy the war file to the `webapps` folder of Tomcat and start it.
8. Start a browser of your choice and call http://localhost:8080/REST-Example/rest/UserService/users, where `REST-Example` is the name of the war file without the file extension.

If you're using Maven, it would even be simpler: you need to add one or two dependencies and Maven will take care of the rest.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still have the same exception for some reasons. Also why don't you put the 'javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar' file?

Comment: Because Tomcat should contain the Servlet api. What exceptions do you get?

Comment: Same as before :/

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your project structure on the question area? And which version of Tomcat and JDK do you have?

Comment: The screenshot has been added. It is exactly the same structure as yours. I use tomcat 7.0 and java 1.8.0_144

Comment: If you still see `com.tutorialspoint` package in the stacktrace, you've definitly the rest of your first example somewhere. Make sure that you have no two instances of Tomcat and the webapps directory does not contain anything related to this example.

Comment: I checked out what you said and now I have the error you can find in the last update. I actually closed another project who was using `com.tutorialspoint`, and remove any other web-app in tomcat's web-app's folder and it seems that it was related to that somehow. I guess it might just be an eclipse/tomcat related problem.

Comment: It looks better now :-) Now check if the path to the resource is correct: 1. in web.xml there should be `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` 2. `@Path("UserService")` 3. `@Path("users")` on the method 4. and the war file is named `REST-Example.war`.

Comment: I found the problem after all, I think it was coming from my Eclipse. Because when I did everything you did on a new eclipse everything worked fine. Such a stupid error... @ujulu thanks for everything